# 100% CPU Load on Haproxy and 100% Load on Balanced Servers

Tags: node.js, networking, load-balancing, haproxy

2 app servers sit behind a Haproxy server using leastconnections method of load balancing. However every 10-15 seconds, the app servers CPU load will spike from very little to 100%! Haproxy server's load is usually 90-100% on one core.

**Question**: Are the continuous CPU spikes on the 2 app servers due to Haproxy unable to take the loads? Should we be concerned that Haproxy has 100% loads for only 60k connections?

**Haproxy stats**

```
pid = 4359 (process #1, nbproc = 1)
uptime = 0d 17h39m45s
system limits: memmax = unlimited; ulimit-n = 524319
maxsock = 524319; maxconn = 262144; maxpipes = 0
current conns = 63194; current pipes = 0/0
Running tasks: 139/63216
```

---

**Haproxy**
[image]

**App servers**
[image]
[image]

---

**Haproxy**

[image]

**App servers**

[image]
[image]